# Открыть одну форму из другой

Tags: wpf, .net, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Как идеалогически правильно это реализуется по паттерну MVVM?

Допустим, есть некоторое главное окно к которому подключена некоторая VM.

Далее, я хочу по нажатию на кнопку на этом окне открыть еще одно окно, например с какими-то настройками, которые потом применятся на главное окно.

Получается, что VM главного окна должна в себе хранить VM открываемого окна?

Или это неверно и это делается более красиво, но по другому?

Comment: Хранит или создает по требованию, не принципиально. Может вообще к обоим окнам одна и та же VM привязана

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну т.е хранение одной VM внутри другой VM не противоречит паттерну?

Comment: Нет не противоречит. Паттерн про разделение ответственностей. Все VM с его точки зрения равны и он правила им не устанавливает

Comment: Ну ответе в вопросе тогда, да я его закрою. Может так же примеры подвести, что бы ответ был не слишком коротким.